# Recurrence Relation solution

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

How do I solve the following recurrence relation and what kind is it ?
$ a_n = a_{n-1} + c $ ?

where c is constant

Can this relation be considered non-homogenous as $ F(n) = c.n^0 $ ?

Comment: Write it as $ a_n - a_{n-1} = c $. This is nothing but an arithmetic progression. Hopefully you can take it up from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a non-homogeneous relation, the simplest you can think of.

Starting from

$$a_1=a_0+c,$$
you have
$$a_2=a_1+c=a_0+2c,\\
a_3=a_2+c=a_0+3c\\
a_4=a_3+c=a_0+4c\\\cdots$$

Do I need to continue ?

---

The standard way to solve a linear recurrence is by

- solving the homogeneous equation

$$a_n=a_{n-1},$$
i.e. by recurrence
$$a_n=a_0.$$

- finding a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation
  $$a_n=a_{n-1}+c.$$
  As this is a first order equation and the RHS is constant, we will try a linear form
  $$a_n=rn+s.$$
  Plugging in the equation
  $$r(n+1)+s=rn+s+c,$$i.e.
  $$r=c,$$and $s$ undeterminate. To ensure that $a_0=a_0$, we take $s=0$, and

$$a_n=a_0+cn.$$

Comment: Crossed with @user37238.

Answer (score 1):

You can first calculate the first terms of this sequence.

$$\begin{array}{rclclcl}
a_1&=&a_0+c &&&&\\
a_2&=&a_1+c &=& a_0+c+c &=& a_0+2c \\
a_3&=&a_2+c&=& a_0+2c+c &=& a_0+3c \\
a_4&=&a_3+c&=& a_0+3c+c &=& a_0+4c \\
\end{array}$$

Do you see a pattern? Can you prove it?